# Merge 2 remote branchs

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have 2 branches on my project:

- developpement: This is where i work on my local computer. Then, i push on a remote branch which name is developpement too with this command:

  git push origin developpement
- master: I do not do anything with this branch on my local computer. I
  merge my remote developpement branch with remote master branch on
  gitlab web interface (merge request then merge button). This merge
  action fires deployment on my production server.

My question is: How can i launch this merge operation from my local computer, in command line. I have tried to work with git merge, but there is a mistake because it is merging local branches and i want to do it remotly only.

The goal of this operation is to push updates on production server

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'i want to do it remotly only'? They will be merged locally, too.

Comment: Git and GitLab are not the same thing.  Git doesn't know anything about GitLab's merge requests.  You would need to use GitLab's API to [merge a request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#accept-mr).

Comment: You could also use a tool, like [lab](https://zaquestion.github.io/lab/) to [merge a request](https://zaquestion.github.io/lab/lab_mr_merge.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key concept here is to remember that the remote and local repositories are each independent copies of the same content. The easiest way to perform any branch operations is to do it locally and then push the updates to the remote repo. This means you can do something like this:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge development
$ git push
```

Now the remote `master` branch will contain all of the code changes that you deem ready for release. This has the added benefit of keeping your local repo up-to-date with the current release. Be sure to also `git tag` a release so that you can easily return to it for bug fixes in the future.

Comment: Okay but what should i do if i have already pushed dev branch?

Comment: @Bob5421 That doesn't matter. The steps I gave above are the same.

Comment: Will this close the merge request in GitLab?  Or was the goal different and GitLab isn't really involved other than for hosting?

Comment: You also probably want to make sure master is up-to-date with the remote before you merge.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister I am not familiar with GitLab. My guess is that the steps in my answer will perform basically the same thing as accepting the merge request in GitLab. The primary difference is that you would still have to do a `git pull` in order to update your local `master` branch.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It definitely does a similar job, but the OP said "but there is a mistake because it is merging local branches and i want to do it remotly only."  This made it sound like they were trying to perform GitLab's merge request remotely versus a simple, local merge operation.  But, given this is the accepted answer, it looks like the answer really was "I want to merge my branch and update master." :-)

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister The question as I read it is: "How can i launch this merge operation from my local computer, in command line." and my answer is more or less that the you can't do exactly what he's asking but here's steps that will get you the same results.